# Running php codes on the background

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I am about embarking on this massive project. Using php for the server side ,  mysql for the database. It's really important that some part of this application keeps running on the background , algorithms , the database being updated , etc. Even if no one is on the system.  How do I achieve this ??
From personal research, I found out that I can create a from job. But I've not really used that before , and is there a way a from job can be made to run on an endless loop ?

Comment: Use cronjob: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron to run it at specific times. Or use a daemon worker if it has to run at all times.

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to use cron.

Comment: What part of the application has to be running all the time?

Comment: queues, crons, triggers... this is a huge topic and depends on the details.

Comment: Laravel's got pretty good documentation on queues at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a php file which you want to run in background

```
say automate.php
```

Make a cron job which runs at every 30 mins(JUST EXAMPLE) using crontab -e and edit like below

```
0/30 * * * * /path/php automate.php
```

Make sure php is defined in your PATH

Answer (score 0):

@olu The easiest way to get PHP code to run over an over again is to put it inside of a loop that never ends and run the command in headless mode.  You could have a php loop that looks like:

```
public function loop(){
  //Do you stuff here.
  sleep(30); // Wait for 30 seconds.
  loop();
}
loop();
```

When you run a file that calls this loop it will never end.  This will achieve what you want but isn't the best way to perform this task.

On unix/linux there is a job/task scheduler named cron.  http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html
It can be a bit tricky to learn at first but there are lots of examples on how to schedule a cron job.  Ideally this would be a better solution then running a headless loop.

I hope this helps.